# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "FastImageView" was not found in the UIManager in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, photo-gallery

**When I'm writting this code error is showing please let me know, Where i'm worng?**

import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      TouchableOpacity,
      FlatList,
      Modal,
    } from 'react-native';

```
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image'

const Imagegallery = () => (
    <FastImage
        style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
        source={{
            uri: 'https://unsplash.it/400/400?image=1',
            priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
        }}
        resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
    />
)

export default Imagegallery
```

Answer (score 14):

After installing `react-native-fast-image` you have to run pod command in you ios directory.

So run this command :

> cd ios
>   pod install

Then run your project.

Comment: I'm using expo in windows

Comment: fast-image does not support on expo. You have to find alternate solution for this.

Comment: quite late for this, but now it is supported in expo, just run `npm install --save react-native-image-modal@1.0.16` or if you are using yarn `yarn add react-native-image-modal@1.0.16`

Answer (score 5):

It's late but for those who got this error, I think It's better to use RN 60.0 because of the auto-linking feature since they didn't provide manual installation for RN < 60.0.

if you're using RN > 60.0 just paste this to your terminal

```
yarn add react-native-fast-image
```

and then rebuild the app

```
react-native run-android
```

It should now work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try either

- Delete `node_modules`
- Run `npm install`

**OR**

Add these lines and manually link the library

**Settings.gradle**

```
include ':react-native-fast-image'
project(':react-native-fast-image').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fast-image/android')
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
import com.dylanvann.fastimage.FastImageViewPackage;
```

**Podfile**

```
pod 'RNFastImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fast-image'
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens on snack:

https://snack.expo.dev/@johndimm/react-native-fast-image-test

It also fails on my local machine with these dependencies:

```
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
```

Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "FastImageView" was not found in the UIManager.

Answer (score 0):

I am using react-native 0.59.9, which works properly on android with react-native-fast-image 7.0.0.

On iOS you need react-native-fast-image 6.1.1, and in order to prevent the error described in the question, I had to do manual installation (https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/blob/4fa62bb09f65d967977f25ef87eda5f8b7c18cd6/docs/installation-manual.md#ios)

Answer (score 0):

**For Android:**

Check existence of `/build` dir in `node_modules/react-native-fast-imaage/android`

In my case 'FastImageView was not found...' error  was occurring when build dir was absent in android dir because of issue in build.gradle. Correcting the issue of gradle successfully generated build dir and the error was gone.